# How do I efficiently compare users?

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, performance

I have users who can "like" categories. For instance, we may have 2 users:

*John likes apples, oranges, pears*

*Bob likes apples, oranges, pie, cake*

*They both like apples, oranges*

This isn't an issue with two users, but when I imagine scaling it to thousands of users, with thousands of likes, there will be major efficiency concerns.

I need to be able to compare a user with all other users, and determine which likes they have in common.

I have tried array_intersect, but it does not scale. I need a mysql solution.

How would I efficiently return users who share the same likes, and the likes that are shared?

```
users
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

categories
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

likes
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| category_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using array_diff: http://au2.php.net/array_diff? Also, you might want to turn your post into a question before it gets down-voted.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: what's your schema look like?  Typically, best way to handle scaling in MySQL is with good normalization.  I'd imagine a schema with the categories in one table, the users in another, and a 3rd relational table linking the two, would scale quite well.  FWIW, using `array_diff` is a pretty bad solution for scalability, as it will require pulling tons of data back into PHP from mysql, and then handling the data in PHP.  MySQL is waaaay better at handling data than php, categorically, hands down.

Comment: I have updated it with my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following:

```
SELECT user_id, count(category_id) AS count, group_concat(category_id separator "|")
FROM likes
WHERE category_id IN (
    SELECT category_id
    FROM likes
    WHERE user_id=1
)
AND user_id != 1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This will return the user id, the amount of categories shared, and the items shared separated by the pipeline character. Obviously it will need joins to get username and category, but for simplicity/readability, I left them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_intersect($likes1, $likes2){

    sort($likes1);
    sort($likes2);

    $intersect = array();

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    while ($i < count($likes1) and $j < count($likes2)){
        if ($likes1[$i] == $likes2[$j]){
            array_push($intersect, $likes1[$i]);
            $i++;
            $j++;
            }
        else if ($likes1[$i] < $likes2[$j])
            $i++;
        else
            $j++;
    }

    return $intersect;
}
```

Above is what I drummed up and it should be most efficient way of finding intersection of two arrays. I do agree with @DanFarrell though in that MySQL or some database will be way more efficient in managing information when it comes to thousands of users.